# What are the basic rules for manipulating diverging infinite series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

This is something that I played around with in Calc II, and it really confuses me:

$s = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + \ldots = \infty$

$s - s = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + \ldots $

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -  (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + \ldots) $

$s - s = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + \ldots$

$0s \ \ \ \ \ = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + \ldots = \infty$

$\therefore 0 (\infty) = \infty$

I'm aware the $0\cdot\infty$ is indeterminate, so what am I doing wrong? What are the basic rules for manipulating these diverging infinite series?

Comment: A simple and useful rule: don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you don't.

The only way to manipulate them is if you know precisely what you're doing and using renormalization techniques or analytic continuation or something, but those techniques won't be taught for awhile and have specific rules about them.

Long story short, you don't manipulate them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! So, are these techniques just taught in a math-specific degree, or will I pick it up in any STEM-related field?

Comment: Honestly, you would probably find them more in a physics class than math class, although analytic continuation is covered in complex analysis.